# Can we make "estimates" the canonical tag?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Currently, there is currently a [proposal](https://pm.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) to make [estimation](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation) a synonym of [estimating](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimating). However, I think this is backwards: if the choice is only between these two words, then *estimation* should be the canonical tag and *estimating* should be the synonym.

While it's true that [estimating](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimating) has more tagged questions, I think that's an historical artifact. In addition, most of our tags are nouns or gerunds, whereas *estimating* is a verb.

However, we have other options that might be even better. For consistency, and based on the Google Ngram of the [related word forms](http://goo.gl/xiW2bB), I'd really like to see [estimates](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimates) become the canonical link rather than the other two.

Comment: It's possible to reverse the order of the proposed synonym - assuming people is ok with reverting it, it could easily be done. Let's see if there's any community feedback on your question and move this forward!

Comment: Interesting idea. Wonder whether more people search for estimating when dealing with the topic or estimation?

Comment: @MarkPhillips I don't know about search, but in terms of *usage* [estimate](http://goo.gl/xiW2bB) is far and away more common. The plural "estimates" isn't far behind, and is less ambiguous as a tag.

Comment: Should the community consider estimate or estimates as the tag?

Comment: @MarkPhillips "Estimate" can be a noun or a verb. "Estimates" can only be a noun, so that's the word that has my vote.

Comment: Grrrr. Now that I think about it, estimates can be a verb, too. But in isolation, I think it's still less ambiguous. :/ English can be slippery.

Comment: I'm leaning to estimate. But wonder what the community thinks?

Comment: Related discussion here: [Should estimating and estimation be synonyms?](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/q/728/430)